# strpos() não se comportando como devia

Tags: php

O strpos() não está se comportando como devia, sempre retorna FALSE mesmo com as duas strings contendo o valor da variável $checa.

```
<?php
$checa = "https://www.site.com.br/";

$url_ref = $_GET['url_ref']; // Recebe: https://www.site.com.br/login/usuarios/

if( strpos( $url_ref, $checa ) !== false ) {
    echo "Confere" . "<br>\n";
} else {
    echo "Não confere" . "<br>\n";
}
?>
```

Está sempre retornando FALSE ( Não confere ).

Se altero a variável, também dá FALSE

```
<?php
$checa = "Qualquer coisa";

$url_ref = $_GET['url_ref']; // Recebe: https://www.site.com.br/login/usuarios/

if( strpos( $url_ref, $checa ) !== false ) {
    echo "Confere" . "<br>\n";
} else {
    echo "Não confere" . "<br>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Só por desencargo de consciência: teu código também está faltando um `;` na primeira linha?

Comment: @fernandosavio não, ajustei!

Comment: Estranho, não consigo pensar em nada. A não ser dar um print nas duas variáveis e checar no olho o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Como deixei comentado na string de $_GET, é o endereço do site com URL amigável, e nada mais, se contém https://www.site.com.br/ em https://www.site.com.br/login/usuarios/ deveria retornar TRUE e não o FALSE, e altero $checa para qualquer coisa, sempre retorna FALSE.

Comment: Obrigado a todos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiro que validar URLs assim a chance de falhar é altíssima, seguintes pontos problema:

- `strpos` só checa case-sensitive
- `strpos` "pode" (depende de como usa) falhar dependendo do caso
- `strpos` não vai diferenciar https de http
- `strpos` não vai ignorar espaços no começo e fim

Outros problemas:

- Falta `isset` ou `empty`
- `strpos( $url_ref, $checa ) !== false` só checa se contem ou não, o "correto" (teoricamente) seria usar com "ZERO" `strpos( $url_ref, $checa ) === 0) { echo 'confere'`

---

Um sugestão, quer validar URL pelo dominio, então use `parse_url` (e o `trim`) para remover espaços, um código revisado:

```
<?php
$checa = "www.site.com.br"; //Sem http, sem https

if (empty($_GET['url_ref'])) {
    echo "Vazio ou não definido<br>\n"; //Customize a mensagem de erro
} else {
    $url = trim($_GET['url_ref']);

    if ($url == '') {
         echo "Vazio<br>\n"; //Customize a mensagem de erro
    } else {
         $scheme = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);

         if (!in_array($scheme, array('http', 'https'))) {
              echo "Não é HTTP(S)<br>\n"; //Customize a mensagem de erro
         } else {
              $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

              if ($host === $checa) {
                  echo "Confere<br>\n";
              } else {
                  echo "Não confere<br>\n";
              }
         }
    }
}
```

---

### Com regex (preg_match)

Claro que poderia usar regex também, o que até reduziria um pouco o código, assim:

```
<?php
//NÃO passe o http, sem https
//preg_quote escapa caracteres que podem after a regex, no exemplo converte pontos em `\.`
$checa = preg_quote("www.site.com.br");

if (empty($_GET['url_ref'])) {
    echo "Vazio ou não definido<br>\n"; //Customize a mensagem de erro
} elseif (preg_match("#^https?://{$checa}(/|$)#", trim($_GET['url_ref']))) {
    echo "Confere<br>\n";
} else {
    echo "Não confere<br>\n";
}
```

Explicando a regex:

```
^https?://www\.site\.com\.br(/|$)
 ^         ^                 ^
 |         |                 |
 |         |                 |
 |         |                 +--- Checa se tem barra `/`, se não tiver deve ser o final das string, caso contrário é uma dominio invalido
 |         |
 |         +--- Url passada na variavel, ela esta com \. no lugar de pontos, porque `.` é um caractere usado para expressões regulares, então o preg_quote o escapou
 |
 +--- Verifica se começa com HTTP ou HTTPS, o `?` após o `s` faz ele ser "opcional"
```

Comment: Obrigado, perfeito!

Comment: @EliseuB. se estiver usando o preg_match troque `https?://{$checa}(/|$)` por `^https?://{$checa}(/|$)`, foi falha minha, faltava o `^`